# Giving a user permission to a folder within the root folder

Tags: permissions

In my root folder, I have a folder called app (e.g. `/root/myapp`). This `/root/app` folder is owned by the user root, and the group `team`. I have this applied to the entire directory by using `chown -R root:team /root/myapp`; however I have a user who is a part of the `team` group and they are unable to access this folder.

```
 ⚡ root@dev  ~/myapp   dev ●  ls -la                                 
total 10568                                                                       
drwxrwxr-x 18 root team    4096 Aug 11 21:44 .                                  
drwx------  9 root root      4096 Aug 11 21:47 ..                                 
-rw-rw-r--  1 root team     341 Jun 17 02:17 .env                               
drwxrw-r-x  8 root team    4096 Aug 11 21:47 .git                               
-rw-rw-r--  1 root team    1573 Aug 11 15:53 .gitignore                                       
-rw-rw-r--  1 root team    4405 Jul 30 15:11 Gemfile                            
-rw-rw-r--  1 root team   13315 Aug  3 17:18 Gemfile.lock                       
-rw-rw-r--  1 root team     384 Jun 17 02:11 README.md                          
-rw-rw-r--  1 root team     227 Jun 17 02:11 Rakefile                           
drwxrw-r-x 13 root team    4096 Aug 11 20:23 app                                
drwxrw-r-x  2 root team    4096 Jun 17 02:11 bin                                
drwxrw-r-x  3 root team    4096 Jun 17 02:11 cfn-templates                      
drwxrw-r-x  5 root team    4096 Aug 11 15:54 config                             
-rw-rw-r--  1 root team     130 Jun 17 02:11 config.ru                          
drwxrw-r-x  3 root team    4096 Aug 11 16:08 db                                 
drwxrw-r-x  2 root team    4096 Aug 11 16:49 doc                                             
drwxrw-r-x  6 root team    4096 Aug 11 20:23 lib                                
drwxrw-r-x  2 root team    4096 Jun 17 02:27 log                                
-rw-rw-r--  1 root team   34733 Aug 11 16:50 models.dot                         
-rw-rw-r--  1 root team 4439122 Aug 11 16:50 models.png                         
drwxrw-r-x  2 root team    4096 Jun 17 02:11 nginx                              
drwxrw-r-x 51 root team    4096 Jun 17 02:27 node_modules                       
-rw-rw-r--  1 root team   14122 Jun 17 02:27 package-lock.json                  
-rw-rw-r--  1 root team     706 Jun 17 02:11 package.json                       
drwxrw-r-x  2 root team    4096 Aug  3 18:38 public                             
drwxrw-r-x  2 root team    4096 Jun 17 02:11 storage                            
drwxrw-r-x 10 root team    4096 Jun 17 02:11 test                               
drwxrw-r-x  5 root team    4096 Jun 17 02:25 tmp                                
drwxrw-r-x  2 root team    4096 Jun 17 02:11 vendor
```

When I run `groups user1`, I can see that `user1` is in the `team` group:

```
 ⚡ root@dev  ~/myapp   dev ●  groups user1                                                                                                                     
user1 : user1 team
```

In that user's home directory, I have created a symlink in the following manner: `ln -s /root/myapp /home/user1/myapp`; however, if I try to cd into that directory under that user, I get `permission denied`.

Any idea what could be causing this? From what I can understand, anyone on the team group should be able to read, write, or execute to the entire directory.

Here's an ls from user`'s home directory as the` user` user:

```
│user1@dev ~ % ls -la                                             
│total 84
│drwxr-xr-x 3 user1 user1  4096 Aug 11 21:55 .
│drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root     4096 Aug 11 21:17 ..
│-rw------- 1 user1 user1    29 Aug 11 21:19 .bash_history
│-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1   220 Apr  4  2018 .bash_logout
│-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1  3771 Apr  4  2018 .bashrc
│-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1     0 Jun 23 04:40 .cloud-locale-test.skip
│-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1   807 Apr  4  2018 .profile
│drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root     4096 Aug 11 21:17 .ssh
│-rw------- 1 user1 user1   695 Aug 11 21:32 .viminfo
│-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 42357 Aug 11 21:19 .zcompdump
│-rw------- 1 user1 user1   673 Aug 11 21:55 .zsh_history
│-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1  1295 Aug 11 21:21 .zshrc
│lrwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1    10 Aug 11 21:18 myapp -> /root/myapp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Changing the rights of the "/root 'folder is an important security flaw, and should never be changed** and should never be done!

Your "myapp" folder should not be found here, but either in a "/home" or in /opt or in a /usr/local/share

At your own risk ...

for your question, the creation of files/folders to be read/write/created by a "group" you need:

- an "**umask 0002**" in the "**.bashrc**" file(s) of the user(s)
- that the "parent" folder *(root of the tree)* be with the following rights:

  chmod g=rwxs FolderName
- that each user concerned are in the same "group" as the group 0 of the parent folder

the `s` options create new file/folder with the groupe of the parent folders
Thus the users belonging to the group will be able to use this folder and each folder / create will have the rights for the common "group"

Use Linux like linux must be used, note like windows or anything else, under penalty of ending up having an unstable system and a real hack nest

Comment: Thanks. I moved this outside of the root folder and I'm all good to go. Thanks for this suggestion. This is much easier than trying to manage permissions in the root folder with this risk.

Comment: under Linux "root" is "god" ;) hands off :)    in the same idea, have never "work" via the "root" account, if necessary, use "sudo"